# DJANGO > 2.2 - Unique together on foreign keys A, B OR foreign keys A, B, C

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

In Django 2.2, you can get rid of **`unique_together`** in favor of a **`constraints`** list with a `UniqueConstraint` class that can be handy because it has a *`condition`* arg.

**MyObject** has three foreign keys, one is optional.

```
class MyObject(ModelBase):
    parent=... # mandatory
    source=... # mandatory
    subsource=... # optional

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["parent", "source", "subsource"],    
                name="unique_subsource"
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["parent", "source"],
                condition=models.Q(subsource=None),
                name="unique_source",
            ),
        ]
```

Imagine I try to create successively the following objects and the expected validation:

```
parent   source   subsource   valid?
1.       1.       1.          yes
1.       1.       2.          yes
1.       1.       -           yes
1.       1.       -           no
1.       1.       3.          yes
1.       2.       -           yes
...
```

So I wrote two tests:

```
def test_unique1(self):
    """ unique parent/source/subsource """
    parent = ParentFactory()
    source = SourceFactory()
    subsource = SubsourceFactory()
    MyObjectFactory(parent=parent, source=source, subsource=subsource)
    myobj = MyObjectFactory.build(parent=parent, source=source, subsource=subsource)
    self.should_raise_validation_error(myobj)

def test_unique2(self):
    """ unique parent/source """
    parent = ParentFactory()
    source = SourceFactory()
    subsource = SubsourceFactory()
    MyObjectFactory(parent=parent, source=source)
    myobj = MyObjectFactory.build(parent=parent, source=source)
    self.should_raise_validation_error(myobj)
```

But the latter does not raise any validation error:

```
.....F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_unique2
unique parent/source/subsource
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sebastiennicolaidis/dev/python/scientcap/macrovars/tests/models/test_dsflink.py", line 50, in test_unique2
    self.should_raise_validation_error(dsflink)
  File "/Users/sebastiennicolaidis/dev/python/scientcap/shared/tests/base_model_test.py", line 9, in should_raise_validation_error
    instance.full_clean()
AssertionError: ValidationError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.141s
```

### [UPDATE 2] output of the sqlmigrate:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Change Meta options on dataset
--
--
-- Change Meta options on dsforecast
--
--
-- Alter unique_together for dsflink (0 constraint(s))
--
ALTER TABLE "macrovars_dsflink" DROP CONSTRAINT "macrovars_dsflink_parent_id_source_id_73901780_uniq";
--
-- Create constraint unique_subsource on model dsflink
--
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_subsource" ON "macrovars_dsflink" ("parent_id", "source_id", "subsource_id") WHERE "subsource_id" IS NOT NULL;
--
-- Create constraint unique_source on model dsflink
--
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_source" ON "macrovars_dsflink" ("parent_id", "source_id") WHERE "subsource_id" IS NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the [**`sqlmigrate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) that the migration that added these constraints generates?

Comment: Added but needs a bit of translation `dsflink` => `my_obj`, and `app_name` is `macrovars`

Comment: At first sight, it looks like it never added the second unique constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution would be to create both the constraint with condition.

```
class MyObject(ModelBase):
    parent=... # mandatory
    source=... # mandatory
    subsource=... # optional

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["parent", "source", "subsource"],    
                condition=models.Q(subsource__isnull=False),  # <- filter subsource is null
                name="unique_subsource"
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["parent", "source"],
                condition=models.Q(subsource__isnull=True),
                name="unique_source",
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: Now it's the two validations that are not raised (I updated the sql migrate output) but I suspect `condition` to remove validation at Django level.

Comment: The _Validation of Constraints_ paragraph.

Comment: hmm, that's weird, ideally it should pick one of the two constraint

Comment: @Sebabouche I checked locally, it is working as expected.